# AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__', Versions are incompatible?

Tags: tensor, h5py

Currently using tensorflow version 2.7.0 and h5py version 3.1.0.
I have tried installing and reinstall both.

This code:

```
import tensorflow
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (26, )))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model_history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data = (X_test, y_test),
                      epochs = 100)
```

Results in the following:

```
AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
pip install h5py==2.9
```